# Rollup bundle using exports instead of module.exports

Tags: node.js, rollupjs

I have a library I am bundling using rollup and this is a section from the `rollup.config.js` file:

```
export default {
  input: `src/${libraryName}.ts`,
  output: [
    { file: pkg.main, name: camelCase(libraryName), format: 'cjs', sourcemap: true },
    { file: pkg.module, format: 'es', sourcemap: true },
  ],

  ....
}
```

It generates two files `dist/libname.umd.js` and `dist/libname.es5.js`. I have confirmed from putting a `console.log` statement in both the files that using `require('libname')` loads the `dist/libname.umd.js`. However, the following line:

```
var x = require('libname').X
console.log(x) // This is undefined
```

prints `undefined`. So, I tried to edit the `dist/libname.umd.js` file manually and at the bottom of the file I saw:

```
exports.X = X;
```

with the overall variable `X` being bundled somewhere above in the file. I modified this to:

```
module.exports.X = X;
```

and then it seems to work. I am a bit new to node/js so I wasn't sure if it this is the way to be exporting modules, but on reading a blog post (http://www.hacksparrow.com/node-js-exports-vs-module-exports.html) it turns out both of them should be fine? I am still a bit unclear on this one though.

Also, when I simply did this:

```
console.log(require('libname')
```

it prints `[Function: uniqSetWithForEach]` and `console.log(require('libname')())` prints `[]`.

**EDIT** So for the time being, just so that I can continue my work I have modified `rollup.config.ts` to add an `outro`:

```
export default {
  ...
  output: [
      { file: pkg.main, name: camelCase(libraryName), format: 'cjs',
        sourcemap: true,
        outro: 'module.exports = Object.assign({}, module.exports, exports)'
      }
  ]
  ...
}
```

and this seems to do it for now, but I'm pretty sure it's not a clean solution.

Comment: Worth mentioning that it doesn't work for default exports (cases where you would have written `module.exports = MyComponent`). Really saved me on a current project. Thanks for this solution!

Comment: That outro feature is extremely handy! I modified your solution just slightly to `outro: 'module.exports = Object.assign({}, module.exports, exports.default)'` Did you have any luck finding a cleaner solution?